# How to integrate YouTrack with IntelliJ using Google Account?

Tags: intellij-idea, google-account, youtrack

I have created YouTrack account logging in with my Google account. Because of that, I don't have any password configured in YouTrack. I'd like to integrate YT with IntelliJ Issues - it is impossible without password...
Any ideas how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The solution is logout and then reset password for registered google email. After this, Hub login will be created with new password.